# Connecting multiple vsts repos at a time through ssh connection is throwing "Failed to start SSH session" error

Tags: azure-devops

I'm unable to open multiple sessions to VSTS through SSH for a given user...if it is more than 18 Connections it is throwing Failed to start SSH session.I need to clone more than 18 repositories at a time on my server and thus causing error..
returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
 or 
ERROR    -> Failed to start SSH session: Failed getting banner

Comment: How did you connect multiple VSTS repos with the SSH? Could you please share the build/release definitions or other related steps/commands in your scenario?

Comment: i'm trying to do git clone through Jenkinsfile on a build server. I have included git checkout in the Jenkinsfile to clone repos on to the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there will be a limitation with the value of **MaxStartups** on SSH configutation, but we can not freely change the value on VSTS SSH server:

> When using SSH on a large number of systems to connect to a
>           single system using an SSH utility (e.g. you issue a command to to
>           copy a file using scp from the remote computers to a single host)
>           and when these connections require authentication (i.e. you are
>           going to authenticate with a password), the sshd daemon at that
>           location may refuse connections after the number "**MaxStartups**" limit
>           in `sshd_config` is exceeded. **This is expected behavior;** **sshd uses this mechanism to
>           prevent DoS attacks from unauthenticated sources.** Please tune
>           sshd_config and reload the SSH daemon, or **consider using the
>           ~/.ssh/authorized_keys mechanism for authentication** if you encounter
>           this problem.

So, just try to [Set up SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts#set-up-ssh-key-authentication), then [Clone the Git repository with SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts#step-3-clone-the-git-repository-with-ssh).

Similar threads:

- [Unable to start SSH session or migration: Failed getting banner](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213911945-Unable-to-start-SSH-session-or-migration-Failed-getting-banner)
- [git ssh cloning fails if many parallel ssh sessions are active](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/152710/git-ssh-cloning-fail-is-many-parallel-ssh-session.html)

---

**UPDATE**:

Since we don't have access to VSTS SSH server, So alternatively you can change to clone using https.

Comment: We are using cloud VSTS for our code base.Since we are using it as a service we don't have access to the servers to make those changes.

Comment: @Anudeep Yeah, we can not make those changes, So suggest you just try to Set up SSH key authentication, then Clone the Git repository with SSH. Have you tried that?

Comment: Since we don't have access to VSTS SSH server we change to clone using https as an alternate way.